# Did this ever happen in the history of Spider-Man?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In the end credits of *Spider-Man: Far From Home*,

> Mysterio reveals that Peter Parker is Spider-Man. Spider-Man's identity was always a secret to the world (at least in the films).

Only a few people knew Peter is Spider-Man.

So I was wondering if something like this happened before, (i.e., the villain

> revealing Spider-Man's identity.)

I am looking for answers that include animated films and TV shows as well as live-action films and TV shows.

Comment: Are you asking if anyone know Peter Parker is the Spider-Man or someone else revealing Peter Parker is Spider-Man to the world?

Comment: It happened at the end of Ultimate Spider Man I  think

Comment: In comics, so many times, in the show to a bunch of people, not the whole world I remember of and that also get retcon every time.

Answer (score 3):

For an example of it happening in adaptations: if you have seen Spider-Man: Into the Spiderverse they reveal that Peter Parker is Spider-Man in the very beginning to the world.

As the comments mention it has happened multiple times in the comics, in the various different universes. Sometimes Peter himself reveals it to the world, like in the Civil War comic arc.

When you ask if something like this happened before are you also looking for superhero types revealing their true identity, or just Spider-Man? The trope of "Secret Identity Unmasking" is well established and common place, [this website](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheUnmasking) handily give examples in all types of media.